# Parke-Taylor formula and MHW-amplitudes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, quantum-chromodynamics, helicity, gluons

In Matthew Schwartz *Quantum Field Theory and Standard Model* the author presents the Parke-Taylor formula

> $\tilde{M}(1^+2^+...j^-...k^-...n^+) = \frac{\langle j k \rangle^4}{\langle 1 2 \rangle  \langle 2 3 \rangle  \langle 3 4 \rangle ... \langle n 1 \rangle}$

(Chapter 27 Gluon scattering and the spinor-helicity formalism, page.550) to calculate MHW amplitudes for $n$-gluon amplitudes. Moreover the reader can find an explicit example of this formula on page 558

> $\tilde{M}(1^-2^-3^+4^+5^+6^+7^+) = \frac{\langle 1 2 \rangle^4}{\langle 7 1 \rangle \langle 1 2 \rangle \langle 2 3 \rangle \langle 3 4 \rangle \langle 4 5 \rangle \langle 5 6 \rangle \langle 6 7 \rangle }$

So far so good. But one thing makes me wonder: How can I see which gluons are incoming and which ones are outgoing? Is there some "convention" that I am missig, e.g. all particles with one helicity are incoming and the rest of the particles with the other helicity are outgoing? Otherwise I simply do not understand, whether $\tilde{M}(1^-2^-3^+4^+5^+6^+7^+)$ refers to $\tilde{M}(1^- + 2^- \rightarrow 3^+ + 4^+ + 5^+ + 6^+ + 7^+)$, $\tilde{M}(1^- + 2^- + 3^+ \rightarrow 4^+ + 5^+ + 6^+ + 7^+)$ or $\tilde{M}(1^- + 2^- + 3^+ + 4^+  \rightarrow 5^+ + 6^+ + 7^+)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As a convention, all the gluons are outgoing. One can interpret $M[1^- 2^- 3^+ 4^+ 5^+]$ as $3^- 4^- \rightarrow 1^- 2^- 5^+$. This also relates to why these class of amplitudes are called MHV, Maximum Helicity Violating.

Comment: Hi!  Please use MathJax (i.e. LaTeX) to typeset your equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/